# Unable to save/retrieve data from core data store in swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am trying to make a simple app to store and retrieve User data.

Have a RegisterViewController.swift with fields (name,loginUsername,loginPassword,photo) which Users enter to register.

I have a User.swift class to save this information in an object

Using CoreData, I have setup "Users" entity with the 4 fields as attributes.

I have referred the following links to save and retrieve data to the Users table.
https://medium.com/xcblog/core-data-with-swift-4-for-beginners-1fc067cca707. 
https://www.bobthedeveloper.io/blog/beginner-guide-to-core-data-in-swift

However, I do not see any data being saved or retrieved when I debug. Neither do I see any exceptions.

Following is the snippet of code

```
let name = self.name.text;
let loginUsername = self.loginUsername.text;
let loginPassword = self.loginPassword.text;
let photo = self.photo.image;

print("Setting user data in the User object");
user = User(name: name!, loginUsername: loginUsername!, loginPassword: loginPassword!, photo: photo)!;

print("store data in DB")
//Setup delegate and context 
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate;
let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Users", in: context);
let newUser = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: context)

//Set values for the attributes        
newUser.setValue(name, forKey: "name")
newUser.setValue(loginUsername, forKey: "loginUsername")
newUser.setValue(loginPassword, forKey: "loginPassword")
//TODO: store the photo

//Save data         
do {
    print("Trying to same")
    try context.save()
 } catch {
    print("Failed to save user")
    let nserror = error as NSError
    fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
 }

 //Method 1: to get Users after saving       
 do {
     usersSaved = try context.fetch(Users.fetchRequest())
 } catch {
     print("Failed to fetch users")
     let nserror = error as NSError
     fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
 }

 //Method 2: to get Users after saving
 var usersSaved: [Users] = []
 let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Users");
 request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
 do {
    let result = try context.fetch(request)
     print("Trying to fetch")
     for data in result as! [NSManagedObject] {
         print(data.value(forKey: "name") as! String)
     }
  } catch {
    print("Failed")
  }
```

This is my User.swift class

```
class User {

    //MARK: Properties
    var name: String;
    var loginUsername: String;
    var loginPassword: String;
    var photo: UIImage? = nil;

    //MARK: Initialization
    init?(name: String, loginUsername: String, loginPassword: String, photo: UIImage?) {

        //Initialization should fail if there is no name or username or password
        if (name.isEmpty || loginUsername.isEmpty || loginPassword.isEmpty) {
            return nil;
        }

        //Initialize stored properties
        self.name = name;
        self.loginUsername = loginUsername;
        self.loginPassword = loginPassword;
        self.photo = photo;
     }
}
```

I have looked online for answers but was unable to figure it out. Any pointers or suggestions would really help me progress..

Comment: You code will be much simpler if you use the `Users` `NSManagedObject` class that Core Data has made for you. What output do you get? Do you get any errors thrown?  In your first fetch code you don't do anything with the data you get.

Comment: Also you have way too many !  Don't get into the habit of using force unwrapping and force downcasting just to keep the compiler happy. Use conditional unwrapping and conditional downcast to write more reliable code

Comment: @Paulw11, Appreciate your response. As you suggested, I am using the Users object of Core Data. The User.swift was just to see if I can store data as objects. I do not get any message or errors thrown. You are right that I am not doing anything with the data but just by checking the SQLite file and using the debugger I do not see any data returned or stored. Do you want me to change something in the code and try?

Comment: But you aren't using the `User` object. You are creating an NSManagedObject from an NSentity rather than a `User` from your context. You are als using `setValue` instead of using the `User` properties. Your code is very old fashioned.  I don't know why the author used that style in a modern tutorial

Comment: @Paulw11, yes I followed the articles as a starter. Could you point me to the right articles or ways to use CoreData instead of what I have?

Answer (score 0):

I am answering my own question for those who might face this issue. Thank you @Paulw11 for the suggestions. Xcode acts weird and I had to do Project -> Clean multiple times and delete DerivedData folder before the CoreData entities got resolved.

This is what I did

```
func storeUserData() {

    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate;
    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

    //store data
    let newUser = Users(context: context);
    newUser.name = self.name.text;
    newUser.loginUsername = self.loginUsername.text;
    newUser.loginPassword = self.loginPassword.text;

    appDelegate.saveContext();

    //retrieve data
    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Users");
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
    do {
        print("Fetching from DB")
        let result = try context.fetch(request)
        //printing data
        for data in result as! [NSManagedObject] {
            print(data.value(forKey: "name") as! String)
            print(data.value(forKey: "loginUsername") as! String)
            print(data.value(forKey: "loginPassword") as! String)
        }
    } catch {
        print("Failed to fetch")
        let nserror = error as NSError
        fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
    }
}
```